# invalid online address in Flutter&GetX

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, flutter-getx

1. I upload image to Firebase Storage. (Firebase Storage created a Url for this image.)
2. I created a field called ImageUrl in a document. And I saved this Url in document.
3. In App, I get documents and I get all documents' ImageUrl, If Message Document has a ImageUrl.
4. I used `Image.network(src)` Widget. I wrote document's ImageUrl inside this widget.
5. then I got this error:

```
Exception has occurred.
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Invalid internet address firebasestorage.googleapis.com)
```

6. when I use `print("$imageUrl");` it shows Url.
7. I used another image Url in Google Images. App worked same with it.

I wrote "A" and "B" in second code block and I wrote "A"'s and "B"'s results end of the question.

I am using GetX in Flutter.

In ControllerPage, I am getting data from Firebase then I am saving into Model Class.
my MessageController.dart

```
class MessagesControllers extends GetxController {

  List<Messages> messagesList = <Messages>[].obs;

  Future<void> getMessages (String number, String siteKey) async {
    try {
      QuerySnapshot messages = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("subscribers")
      .doc(number).collection("sites").doc(siteKey).collection("messages").get();
      messagesList.clear();
      for(final message in messages.docs) {
        if(message['status'] == 'Active') {
        messagesList.add(
          Messages(
            message.id, 
            message["date"], 
            message["message"], 
            message["imageUrl"],
            false
          )
        );
        }
      }
      update();
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar(
        "MessagesControllers, ERROR", "> $e",
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
    }
  }
}
```

I am using Controller in this Page.

```
class MessagesPage extends StatelessWidget {

  MessagesControllers messagesControllers = Get.put(MessagesControllers());
  int actionController = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<MessagesControllers>(
      init: MessagesControllers(),
      initState: (_) { },
      builder: (messagesControllers) {
        if(HomePage.isSignOut==false) {
          messagesControllers.getMessages(number, siteKey);        
        } else {
          Get.delete<MessagesControllers>();
        }
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: npAppBar(siteName, true),
          body: buildMessagesField(context),
        );
      });
  }

  Widget buildMessagesField(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding:  EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: Get.height*0.02),
      child: Obx(() =>ListView.builder(
        itemCount: messagesControllers.messagesList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
A -->>  print("message's imageUrl => ${messagesControllers.messagesList[index].imageUrl}");
        return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: Get.width*0.05,
              vertical: Get.height*0.005),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color.fromRGBO(60, 115, 110, 0.15),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),),
              child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                Get.to(() => MessagePage());
              },
              title: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: Get.height*0.008),
                child:
                    Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border( bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black))
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          const Spacer(),
                          Expanded(flex: 10,child: Text(date, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                          const Spacer(),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 3,
                            child: PopupMenuButton(
                              iconSize: 18,
                              onSelected: (value){
                              },
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => [
                              PopupMenuItem(
                                child: const Row(children: [
                                  Icon(Icons.delete, color: ColorConstants.deleteColor,),
                                  Text("  Delete",),],
                                  ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  deleteMessage(index);
                                },
                              ),
                            ]),
                          ),
                                                
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
              ),
              subtitle: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 0,
                  vertical: Get.height*0.005 
                  ),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    messagesControllers.messagesList[index].imageUrl.toString() == "" 
                    ? const SizedBox()
                    : Expanded(
                      flex: imageFlex,
                      child: SizedBox(
 B --->>              child: Image.network("${messagesControllers.messagesList[index].imageUrl}"))
                    ), 
                      const Spacer(),
                      messageLength == 80 ?
                        Expanded(
                          flex: textFlex,
                          child: Text(
                            "> ${messagesControllers.messagesList[index].message.toString().substring(0, messageLength)}...",
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Colors.black
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Expanded(
                          flex: textFlex,
                          child: Text(
                          ">  ${messagesControllers.messagesList[index].message}",
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            color: Colors.black
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                  ],
                ),
              ),               
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      )),
    ); 
  }
  void deleteMessage (int index) {
    GetMessageID().deleteMessage(number, siteKey, messagesControllers.messagesList[index].id);

  }
}
```

A ->

```
[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /MessagesPage
D/EGL_emulation( 4796): app_time_stats: avg=300.99ms min=256.32ms max=353.75ms count=4
2
I/flutter ( 4796): message's imageUrl => 
I/flutter ( 4796): message's imageUrl => https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/.....
```

B ->

```
Exception has occurred.
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Invalid internet address firebasestorage.googleapis.com)
```

[image: my firestore]